# Can I make two containers (e.g. Grid and Canvas) take the same space to combine their abilities?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, user-interface, panels

I have the following layout:

[image]

The `Rectangle`s are placed using a `Grid`. On top of that, I want to add more "fluid" stuff, like `Path`s and lines that would be located dynamically.

For instance:

- the lines between the `Rectangle`s, are stretched from one `Rectangle`'s mid-point to the mid-point of the one below it
- The left-manually-drawn-ugly-red-"path" originate from the mid-point of the left-half of the top-`Rectangle`, and go to the mid-point of the left `Rectange` below it.

So the question is: the `Rectangle`s match `Grid` behavior, other stuff, like the lines, match `Canvas` behavior. How do I use the advantages of both these containers? can I lay one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can lay the Canvas on top of a Grid, but you probably don't want to.

```
<Grid x:Name="container">
    <!-- We use this to put the two items in the same location -->
    <!-- i.e. Row="0" Column="0" is implicit for both the canvas and the grid below-->
  <Grid x:Name="rectangleGrid"/>
  <Canvas x:Name="shapeCanvas"/>
</Grid>
```

It really is that simple, but lets have a look at what we have now.

- The `shapeCanvas` will be in front of the `rectangleGrid` (and if it isn't just tweak its `ZIndex`).  If it has a non-transparent `BackColor` then you won't of course see the `rectangleGrid`, so you will need to sort that out.
- If we want to line up the right hand red-line of yours we need to work out where to draw it from. Given that gridColumns don't expose sizes, then that's `leftRectangle.ActualWidth + leftRectangle.Margin.Left + leftRectangle.Margin.Right  + rightRectangle.Margin.Left + (rightRectangle.ActualWidth/2)` and `topRectangle.ActualHeight + topRectangle.Margin.Top + someConstantForHowTallThatSpacerRowIs + rightRectangle.Margin.Top + (rightRectangle.Height/2)`. Ouch
- If we resize the `container`, then the `rectangleGrid` will also resize, but if you have used start-sizing for your columns then the rectangles all just resized. Now I have to go and recalculate all the sizes again.

So at this point, I'd start asking myself if I really wanted the `rectangleGrid` to handle the sizing or maybe I should just put everything into the `Canvas`.

- You don't need to resize (although be careful because there are lots of [high DPI](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LivingAHighDPIDesktopLifestyleCanBePainful.aspx) screens out there now)
- If you resize then the sizes are much simpler (e.g. if we assume that our margins are rectangles are 3/4 of the size and the margins 1/8 each side) so that redline top point now becomes `shapeCanvas.Size *11/16` and `(shapeCanvas.Height - someConstantForHowTallThatSpacerRowIs)/14`

Comment: Thanks. I would have placed everything inside a `Canvas`, but I need the ability to see the base state in design-time. If I position everything programmatically, the design-time won't reflect any of that.

Comment: If you encapsulate the canvas in a `UserControl` then it will, because the Design Time of the Window (or whatever you are hosting the control in) will be runtime for the canvas :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mix and match your controls at all... you can chose either a `Gird` *or* a `Canvas` control to draw on using a `Path` element.  Clearly, I don't want to do it all for you, so this is just a basic example of drawing in a `Grid`:

The end result:
[image]

The XAML:

```
<Grid Width="800">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Rectangle.RadiusX" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Rectangle.RadiusY" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Path Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Data="M0,0 0,100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Path Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Data="M0,0 0,100" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Path Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0 A 100,100 90 0 0 -100,100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,150,0" />
    <Path Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Data="M0,0 A 100,100 90 0 1 100,100" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="{x:Null}" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,-250,0" />
</Grid>
```

You can also find the syntax that you need to use in the `Path.Data` property in the [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.